# Take 5 images a second, triggered by motion sensor, switching between 2 cameras depending on time

Tags: camera, sensor, image, raspivid, gstreamer

I'm working on a project similar to a security camera with a Raspberry Pi NoIR Camera Module v2 and a FLIR Lepton 3.5 on a purethermal 2.

I am somewhat new to this and am not sure how to proceed.  I need to have the program trigger from a motion detector (PIR) attached to a GPIO pin and activate either the camera or FLIR depending on the time of day.  I also need the system to store 5 jpegs a second of the stream while there is still motion. I am currently attempting to run video and use gstreamer to convert certain frames to jpeg because this seems more reliable than the still features.  Any help would be appreciated.

Does anyone know how to capture and switch between these cameras as well as continue the stream while there is motion?

Comment: forgot to mention max resolution required is 640x480

Comment: Yes, so I found a cheapy Logitech webcam with 640 x 480 pixels can do the job well.   Even AlphaGo cannot handle higher resolution than a chess board. RpiCamV2 with 3280 × 2464 pixels is a ridicuious overkill.  You need to reduce RpiCam to 640x480 to do AI (and from RGB to black and white, my goodness!).  That was why I abandoned RpiCam and switched to LogiTechCam.

Comment: Then I found web cameras a bit bulky.  I also tried Rpi high resolution type but with wide angle.  Finally I found the narrow angle CCD cameras for parking car, also with cheapy 5" PAL i480 LCD monitor best suited for my home security system.  I am showing some more pictures.  You might like to let me know which more look like yours.

Comment: I just found that the new generation PIR chip AM312 is DSP, low power is is much better than the old chip DS0001.  So I am going to order one from TaoBao. https://unusualelectronics.co.uk/as312-am312-mini-pir-module-review/

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

Let me summarize your project.

1. You have two cameras, one day camera, another, night camera.
2. You have one PIR sensor, connected to Rpi which gets alerted if a naughty cat comes in.
3. If it is day time, Rpi switches on camera and starts streaming video, extracts to 5 jegs a second and stops as soon as the thing has left.
4. Similarly the night camera at night.

***Short Answer***

Some time ago I used Rpi, Rpi Camera, and also cheap Logitech web cameras to do similar things and found many open software tools and libraries helpful.

Now I have learnt how to use python to interface real time clock DS3231.  Perhaps I can do system integration this time, starting with PIR.  Perhaps I can also add Google Tensor Flow cat face detection, ...

[image: pir modules]

[image: web cam and mon]

***References***

[AI to identify cats 2012 and 5000 species 2017 - Dave Gershgorn 2017apr11](https://qz.com/954530/five-years-ago-ai-was-struggling-to-identify-cats-now-its-trying-to-tackle-5000-species/)

[Cats vs Dogs Leveraging Convolutional Neural Networks and Google Colab Free GPU - Greg Surma 2018nov18](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-classifier-cats-vs-dogs-with-convolutional-neural-networks-cnns-and-google-colabs-4e9af21ae7a8)

[Edge TPU - cloud google](https://cloud.google.com/edge-tpu/)

[Coral Local/Offline AI (Mendel/Debian, Tensor Flow Lite, Python) - Google](https://coral.withgoogle.com/)

Edge TPU USB Accelerator (Raspberry Pi, Debian) - USD$74.99
https://coral.withgoogle.com/products/accelerator/
https://coral.withgoogle.com/tutorials/accelerator-datasheet/

***Update 2019apr11htk1049***

***More References***

Adafruit PIR Sensor Tutorial - Introducing PIR
https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/overview

Adafruit PIR Sensor Tutorial - Connecting to PIR
https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/connecting-to-a-pir

Adafruit PIR Sensor Tutorial - Testing PIR
https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/testing-a-pir

PIR BISS00012 Micro Power PIR Motion Detector IC Datasheet - Shanghai JX 2005
http://www.ladyada.net/media/sensors/BISS0001.pdf

PIR BISS00012 Micro Power PIR Motion Detector IC Datasheet in Chinese - Shanghai JX 2005
http://www.ec66.com/market/sheet/biss0001.pdf

AliExpress PIR sensor module catalog
https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-pir-sensor-module.html

TaoBao PIR Sensor Module Catalog
https://risym.tmall.com/search.htm?q=%C8%CB%CC%E5%B8%D0%D3%A6%C4%A3%BF%E9+&navigator=all&_input_charset=&spm=a21bp.7806943.20151106.1

TaoBao HC-SR501 PIR Module CN¥3.60
https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a312a.7700824.w4002-18130655753.30.569b21fci4bMs6&id=589581993055

***Update 2019apr11hkt1210***

*Smart Home Security System Hardware Selection - Final Version*

Now the time has come to do some experiments.

[image: car park, wide angle ccd cameras]

PIR Module Configuration Notes

Now I am looking at my PIR module to decide how to config, based on Adrfruit's instructions.

[image: pir_module]

This is Adafruit's instruction

[image: PIR Config]

Now I know other's modules have two pots, me only one.  Other guys have a jumper to set High Low, me no jumper, but soldered as High.  I need to check up the chip spec to see what High level configs.

Now I am learning how to config the PIR chip

[image: PIR Module config notes]

***Arduino, CircuitPython, but no Raspberry Pi!***

Lady Ada teaches how to test the PIR, then shows example Arduino code, then CircuitPython code - ***BUT RASPBERRY PI CODE IS SKIPPED!***

I don't know circuit python and I am too lazy to learn. What can I do?

[AdaFruit PIR Motion Sensor Arduino and CircuitPython Code Example](https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/circuitpython-code)

/ to continue, ...

Comment: Yes that is a similar setup, i'm just don't understand exactly how to even start with the python code to integrate the motion sensor and determine the cameras.  I have some basic command lines that seem to be running but typically for these cameras to initialize you set a run time to they don't run continuously while there is movement

Comment: Thank your for confirmation.  Let us first see how to talk to PIR using python, and  forget the cameras now.

Comment: I had some basic code that would tell me if there was currently movement or not.  I imagine with this I could use a while to run the cameras I'm just not certain how to make the cameras run for the entirety and then encode the frames.

Comment: import RPi.GPIO as GPIO<br/>
import time<br/>
GPIO.setwarnings(False)<br/>
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)<br/>
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)<br/>
<br/>
while True:<br/>
 i = GPIO.unput(4)<br/>
 if i == 0:<br/>
  print"Movement", i<br/>
 if i == 1:<br/>
  print"No Movement", i<br/>
 time.sleep(1)<br/>

Comment: Ah, I forgot how the PIR thing works.  So I am asking Lada Ada for help.  See your later. https://learn.adafruit.com/pir-passive-infrared-proximity-motion-sensor/overview