# Confused hooking up PIR sensor and programming

Tags: sensor

I'm brand new to coding and new to Raspberry Pi.
Appreciate any help, I've tried to look up various ways on doing this.
I was able to put

Comment: You need to show us the software you are using and a photo of the wiring you have used.

Comment: Try Googling `pir sensor raspberry pi`.    There are many example tutorials.  This one appears to be a very good introduction: https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/how-to-interface-a-pir-motion-sensor-with-raspberry-pi-gpio

Comment: Hi @Mike, Welcome and nice to meet you.  You can search this forum with keyword "PIR". Or my answers: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98371/why-is-pir-motion-sensor-always-on, 

(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102085/commercial-pir-intergration-with-raspberry-pi-zero,

(3) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96362/take-5-images-a-second-triggered-by-motion-sensor-switching-between-2-cameras.  I have 5+ different models of PIR in hand.  Show me a photo of your PIR, and I can try to let you know how to start with wiring and python coding.